# Apache Ant argument to generate portlet only

Tags: ant, liferay, portlet

I'm working with `Liferay` and generating portlets with a Apache Ant-based build.
I want to generate a `portlet project only` without compiling it's codes.
How can I do it? What arguments must be passed to the ant command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 files in the `myProject-xmlportletfactory` folder under the `XmlPortletFactory` folder: build.xml and myProject.xml.
When I run the `ant` in this path, it runs the build.xml.
In the buil.xml file, under the `<target>` tag there are to `<ant>` tags, the first builds services and classes for the project and the second compiles and deploys the project. if I delete the second  tag and run the ant, it will build the project only and dont compile it.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use the create.sh script that is in the portlets directory under [the Plugins SDK](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/the-plugins-s-3) to create a new portlet plugin project.

1. [Install Plugins SDK](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installing-the-sdk)
2. Go into portlets subdirectory on command line
3. Run the create.sh/create.bat and pass two arguments, one for name of portlet project and other for the display name.

All of this is [fully documented here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-a-portl-3) along with how to perform the same task using [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide/overview) (Eclipse plugin for Liferay development).

Comment: Oh! I forgot to say that I first make an Xml file for my project in the `XmlPortletFactory` folder and then execute the `ant` command on it to generate the project. How can I execute the ant command without compiling the project after generating it.

Comment: @Hamid62 why don't you edit your question and state that you're using XmlPortletFactory?